# Stored Procedure Declarations

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, parameters, procedures

In the code below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserCheck (
  IN param1 VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE var1 INT(10);
```

what is the difference between `param1` and `var1`?

Comment: A lot.  One is a passed in parameter, one is a local variable declared within the stored procedure.  One is a `varchar` and one is an `int`.  What are you unclear about?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: @WesPalmer, so rude of you to say that. i am coming from a DB with no stored procedures. Currently I am starting to learn MySQL. Stored procedures are pretty new to me.